# Why is HibernateDaoSupport not recommended?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I've been doing some work with Hibernate 3.5 and Spring 3 recently, I'm fairly new with Hibernate and thought the `HibernateDaoSupport` class in Spring made it nice and easy to use Hibernate with my domain classes.

However, while searching for an unrelated question I saw someone mention that the `HibernateDaoSupport` is not the best way to use Spring and Hibernate. Can anyone shed any light on:

- Why is it not recommended?
- What is the best (or at least the accepted) way to integrate Hibernate and Spring?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Using `HibernateDaoSupport`/`HibernateTemplate` is not recommended since it unnecessarily
ties your code to Spring classes.

Using these classes was inevitable with older versions of Hibernate in order to integrate support of Spring-managed transactions.

However, since Hibernate 3.0.1 you don't need it any more - you can write a code against a plain Hibernate API while using Spring-managed transactions. All you need is to configure Spring transaction support, inject `SessionFactory` and call `getCurrentSession()` on it when you need to work with session.

Another benefit of `HibernateTemplate` is exception translation. Without `HibernateTemplate` the same functionality can be achieved by using `@Repository` annotation, as shown in Gareth Davis's answer.

**See also:**

- [13.3.2 Implementing DAOs based on plain Hibernate 3 API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight)

Comment: Thanks for the input. And thanks for the link to the Spring doc, it's pretty clear actually. I'll mark your post as the answer since it answers my main questions, thanks.

Comment: Alternatively to `SessionFactory` you could use the JPA 2 implementation of Hibernate (inject an `EntityManager` as starting point).

Comment: It's important to note that Spring has dropped HibernateDaoSupport/HibernateTemplate from their Hibernate 4 package. So if you make use of these classes now, you'll have some refactoring to do when you upgrade to Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 18):

For my money there is nothing wrong with using `HibernateDaoSupport`. It isn't deprecated in spring 3.0.

Can you provide the question number that you found, it maybe they where refering to a very specific use case.

The alternative is to use the `@Repository` annotation. This will wire in the same exception translation (one of the big benefits of the `HibernateTemplate`) and allow you to either use your own super class or just simply to avoid extending a third party framework class.

```
@Repository
public class YourFooDao {

    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Foo get(long id){
        return (Foo) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - I still prefer `HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplate`, since they provide a richer API than the raw Hibernate `Session` API.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about @Repository annotation, I'll certainly find out more about it in the docs. I couldn't find the thread where I first saw this mention, sorry.

Comment: @skaffman well if Hibernate has a bad API, then maybe Hibernate shouldn't be used (I only use it as JPA provider)

Comment: @Sean: I didn't say it was a bad API. It's just that Spring's is very slightly better.