# How we can Query object in hibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I want to use Query object in HibernateTemplate.
We can use that Query object with HibernateTemplate but that was deprecated by Spring.

If any one to using other way 
Please guide me

Thanks in advance

Dharmendra

Comment: Could you please share a link to the javadoc of the deprecated method you want to use. I only found saveOrUpdateAll in Spring 3.1's javadoc to be deprecated.

Comment: For completeness:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either pure sql or you can do it by writing simplified queries like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Query query = session.createQuery("FROM TableName where id=:userId");
query.setString("userId", userId);  //userId is of string type Or you can use userId+"" to convert it to string

List<myEntityPOJOName> result = query.list();  //this will return a list of myEntityPOJOName objects
```

Or you can write pure sql inside createQuery() function like below:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("delete from TableName myEntityPOJOName where id=:userId and hId=:hospitalID");
query.setString("userId",myUserID);
query.setString("hospitalID", myHospID);
int row = query.executeUpdate(); //returns a number of updated rows
```

For Hibernate implemented functions like saveOrUpdate(),save() etc. you can take a look at Hibernate docs at http://www.hibernate.org/docs

Comment: Thanks We can do this way, but i want any alternative to do in HibernateTemplate we are using Spring and hibernate

Comment: HibernateTemplate does only connection, session etc. related stuffs, but it doesn't matter whether you use hibernateTemplate or SessionFactory for your Session handling, the queries will remain the same. So for your project if you have used hibernateTemplate then it will create sessions for you and you just need to get your current session (or create a new one) for doing any db related operations..And one more thing, as I know using hibernateTemplate is not preferred in last version of hibernate, instead you can directly inject sessionFactory into your DAO class

Comment: (continue of previous comment) ...without extending HibernateDaoSupport. Here's a link for Hibernate reference doc where it says the same: "NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can also be coded in plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started projects, consider adopting the standard Hibernate3 style of coding data access objects instead, based on SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()." http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html