# Spring with Hibernate DAO layer?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

I am using Spring with Hibernate in my web application and I tend to use `HibernateDaoSupport` because it will open session and close session automatically. I have two entities `Route(route_id, source, destination)` and `Stop(stop_id, latitude, longitude)`. Relation between these two tables is many-to-many. One route can contain many stops and one stop can contain many routes.

`Route.hbm.xml`:

```
<set name="stops" table="route_stop" cascade="all" lazy="false" order-by="stop_id asc">
    <key column="route_id" />
  <many-to-many column="stop_id"  class="com.trackingsystem.model.Stop" />

</set>
```

`Stop.hbm.xml`:

```
<set name="routes" table="route_stop" cascade="all" lazy="false" inverse = "false">
            <key column="stop_id" />
          <many-to-many column="route_id"  class="com.trackingsystem.model.Route" />
        </set>
```

This is the DAO class:

```
public class HibernateRouteStopsDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements RouteStopsDAO{

    public Set<Stop> getStops(Route route){

        return route.getStops();

    }
    public Route getRoute(int routeId){

        return (Route)getSession().get(Route.class, routeId);

    }
    public Route getRoute(String source, String destination){
        Session session = null;
        Route route = null;
        try{
            session = getSession();
            route = (Route)session.createCriteria(Route.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("source", source))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("destination", destination)).list().get(0);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
        }finally{

        }

        return route;

    }
    @Override
    public void persistRoute(Route route) {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = getSession();
            session.save(route);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void addStops(Route route, Stop stop) {
        Session session = null;

        try{
            session = getSession();
            route.getStops().add(stop);
            stop.getRoutes().add(route);
            session.update(route);
            session.update(stop);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
        }finally{
        }
    }
    @Override
    public List<Route> getAllRoutes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = null;
        List<Route> listOfRoutes = new ArrayList<Route>(0);

        try{
            session = getSession();
            listOfRoutes = session.createCriteria(Route.class).list();
            return listOfRoutes;

        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
            return listOfRoutes;
        }finally{

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void updateRoute(Route route) {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = getSession();
            session.update(route);
            session.flush();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
        }finally{

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAllStops(Route route) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session = null;

        try{
            session = getSession();
            session.delete(route);

        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("RouteStopsDAO "+e);
        }finally{
            //session.close();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public Stop getStop(int stopId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Stop) getSession().get(Stop.class, stopId);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Route> getRoutes(String stopName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        List<Stop> stops = getSession().createCriteria(Stop.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("stopName", stopName)).list();

        for(Stop stop : stops){
            routes.addAll(stop.getRoutes());
        }

        return routes;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Stop> getStops(String stopName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        List<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<Stop>();
        for(Route route : getRoutes(stopName)){
            stops.addAll(route.getStops());
        }
        return stops;
    }
    @Override
    public Stop getStop(String stopName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu
        List<Stop> stops =  getSession().createCriteria(Stop.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("stopName", stopName)).list();
        if(stops.size()>0)
            return (Stop)stops.get(0);
        else return null;
    }

}
```

Here I am not understanding, do I need to start the transaction or `HibernateDaoSupport` automatically starts one? Please update my DAO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do.   Since you are using Spring, you can let it manage your transactions for you.  The great thing about Spring is you can add transaction support with little impact on your code.

You need to

1)  Set up a TransactionManager in your configuraiton
2)  Decide how you want to demarcate your transactions.
3)  Remove all the try/catch blocks in your code.  If you leave them in, your transactions won't roll back -- Spring managed transactions typically roll-back when an exception bubbles up, unless you are programmatically managing your transactions.

[Here is the Spring documentation on Transactions.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) It contains examples on how to configure a transaction manager, and how to configure declarative transaction management (letting the container do most of the work for you).

BTW, use of the Spring transaction template is no longer recommended.  [See this as for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why).

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to start the transaction. But using `HibernateDaoSupport` is a bit obsolete. You'd better use JPA `EntityManager` instead of raw hibernate. Then you don't need to extend any class in your DAOs.

Transactions can be started with the [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) support provided by spring. Read the linked documentation, but in short - you annotate a method with `@Transactional` and it starts a transaction. In addition to that it also opens a new session.