# Creating a seperate persists maven module, but I need HibernateDaoSupport?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring mvc application that I have broken up into separate maven modules.

Now in my datalayer module, I seem to be stuck as I need to use HibernateDaoSupport.

Now I don't need to use it, but that is what i have used in the past.

I have a `genericDaoImpl` that looks like:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T, K extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport
        implements GenericDao<T, K> {


    @Override
    public T get(Class<T> type, K id) {
        return super.getHibernateTemplate().get(type, id);
    }


}
```

How can I do this now when my datalayer is in a seperate module that isn't (and shouldn't) be dependant on spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with the same situation by learning from:
[HibernateDaoSupport is not recommended, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why)

and [Hibernate Generic DAO](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/)