# No Session found for current thread using JTA TransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, jta, spring-transactions

I'm having some trouble migrating to hibernate 4 while using a JTA Transaction Manager.
Maybe you can help, cause I'm all out of ideas.

**Software:**

Spring: *3.1.1.RELEASE*
Hibernate: *4.1.3.Final*
Database: *Oracle 11g*
Application: *Ejb 3.0* deployed in *Websphere Application Server 7.0* (using `@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)` to initialize the spring context)

**Spring configuration:**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="myServicePackage,myDaoPackage" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="myModelPackage" />
    <property name="mappingResources" value="queries.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
<!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" /> -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class TradeService {
    @Autowired
    private TradeDao tradeDao;
}
```

**Dao:**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TradeDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Trade getTrade(){
        return (Trade) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("get_trade").uniqueResult();
    }
```

**Throws:**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1041)
at myDaoPackage.TradeDao.getTrade(TradeDao.java:26)
```

***Notes:***

1. I've also tried using `@Transactional` on the service instead of the
   dao. Same result.
2. Similar config, but using *Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE*, *Hibernate 3.6.5.Final*, and TradeDao extending `HibernateDaoSupport` works.

So, does anyone have any ideas?
I've been trying a lot of things all day today.
My head is spinning and I'm annoyed, so I must be missing something very simple, but at this point I can't really tell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working.

As I was expecting I was missing just some small configuration :)

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

I found these configuration options earlier while browsing, but for some reason they didn't work when I tried them. Probably I had something else wrong at that time... (see [Transaction strategy configuration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html) chapter)

Thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much like the problem that this person was having: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?121109-Transaction-Propagations-and-Hibernate-4

That is, HibernateDaoSupport (and, presumably, HibernateTemplate) was creating a Session if one wasn't found on the Thread, whereas it sounds like the new approach does not.

EDIT: I just realized that the included link is using a HibernateTransactionManager. I believe that if you use a JtaTransactionManager and do *not* use a HibernateTemplate, you have to manually apply advice around the target which creates a session.

It might also be something they missed in Spring: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9404

Comment: I don't know if his problem is related or not. 
I was trying to remove all dependencies on `HDaoSupport` and `HTemplate` ([which is the recommended standard now](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight), plus they are [somewhat deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why), 
and org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 package doesn't have them anymore). I can achieve the same thing by using just `@Repository, @Transactional, SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. Anyway, I got it working, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

By default the @Transactional annotation works on interfaces.  Since you're going sans interface, you should add the proxy-target-class="true" attribute to the <tx:annotation-driven /> tag in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but that isn't the problem. `proxy-target-class="true"` is used only to force spring to use CGLIB always (even when using interfaces). By default Spring is smart enough such that if the target object has at least one interface it will create dynamic proxies, otherwise it will use CGLIB. See chapter [8.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)