# Can use same Session Factory for Two Hibernate Templates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is there some mechanism to use one session factory for two hibernate templates.

I have try and it throw bean creation exception.

```
<bean id="auditLogHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="auditLogSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="auditLogLocalHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="auditLogSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Can I do this. 
If Cant let me to know any other way to do it. 
Or cant we do this any way ?

Stack trace

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogLocalHibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [auditlog/conf/auditlog-conf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'localHibernateSession' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appHibernateSessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject

full configuration as below.

```
<alias name="appHibernateSessionFactory" alias="localHibernateSession" />

<bean id="auditLogSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="auditLogDataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>auditlog.domain.AuditLog</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="auditLogHibernateProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditLogHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="auditLogSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="auditLogLocalHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localHibernateSession"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditLogDao" class="auditlog.dao.AuditLogDao" >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="auditLogHibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditLogLocalDao" class="auditlog.dao.AuditLogLocalDao" >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="auditLogLocalHibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="auditLogManager" class="auditlog.service.AuditLogManager" >
        <property name="auditLogDao" ref="auditLogDao" />
        <property name="auditLogLocalDao" ref="auditLogLocalDao" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: What bean creation exception? This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The problem is somwhere else, please post the exception. Also consider not to use HibernateTemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why