# Hibernate sessionFactory or Hibernate Template missing

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate

I have this error everytime I change my `xml` file. Here's  what I got:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managerExpedBitacora' defined in class path resource [config/spring/manager.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required`

Full stack:

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:117)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
... 21 more
```

Here's my `manager.xml`, only refered lines:

```
<bean id="managerExpedBitacora" class="es.myCompany.lq.manager.impl.ManagerExpedBitacoraImpl">
             <property name="daoExpedBitacora" ref="daoExpedBitacora"/>  
</bean>

...
<bean id="managerExpedienteLS" class="es.myCompany.lq.manager.impl.ManagerExpedienteLSImpl">
     ....
     <property name="managerExpedBitacora" ref="managerExpedBitacora" />
     ....
</bean>
```

And here's my `daos.xml`, only some lines:

```
<bean id="daoExpedBitacora" class="es.myCompany.lq.dao.impl.DaoExpedBitacoraHbmImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

As u can see, I have injected the sessionFactory.

And, `applicationContext.xml`, mail part:

```
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/properties.xml"/> 
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/utils.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/bbdd.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/daos.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/manager.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/actions.xml"/>
```

And, part of my `DaoExpedBitacoraHbmImpl.java`:

```
public class DaoExpedBitacoraHbmImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements
    DaoExpedBitacora {
...(methods)
}
```

And, `HibernateDaoSupport.java`, only part of it.

```
public class HibernateDaoSupport extends org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport{
....
}
```

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a `setSessionFactory` if so make sure it is calling the super setter. Also judging from the stack trace snippet (please add the full stack trace) your service is also extending the `HibernateDaoSupport` class

Comment: Can you explain what stuff you have written in DaoExpedBitacoraHbmImpl method.

Comment: I can see that you require the sessionFactory in daoExpedBitacora, but where are you actually providing it?

Comment: @M. Deinum it's full stacktrace, see my question, and thanks for comment. Anyway it's solved by project superior, answer below.

Comment: Thanks all for comment. @M. Deinum it's full stacktrace, see my question, and I don't have a `sessionFactory` setter and it works fine. U r right, my implementation class is also extending that and it's why it fails. @Darshan I have written three methods in my `DaoExpedBitacoraHbmImpl`: `insert`, `get` with ID of same bean, and `select` with id of another associated class, all with `getHibernateTemplate` and `Criteria`. @Jens Schauder I am providing sessionFactory in `spring\orm\hibernate4\support\AutoOpenSessionInviewFilter.java`, which is not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project leader read the code, and said **my `ManagerExpedBitacoraImpl.java`, as an implementation of service, shall not extends `HibernateDaoSupport.java`**. It's a part I didn't post. So before it was like:

```
public class ManagerExpedBitacoraImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ManagerExpedBitacora {

    DaoExpedBitacora daoExpedBitacora;

    public DaoExpedBitacora getDaoExpedBitacora() {
    return daoExpedBitacora;
    }

    public void setDaoExpedBitacora(DaoExpedBitacora daoExpedBitacora) {
    this.daoExpedBitacora = daoExpedBitacora;
    }
....
```

And it should be like:

```
public class ManagerExpedBitacoraImpl implements
    ManagerExpedBitacora {

    DaoExpedBitacora daoExpedBitacora;

    public DaoExpedBitacora getDaoExpedBitacora() {
    return daoExpedBitacora;
    }

    public void setDaoExpedBitacora(DaoExpedBitacora daoExpedBitacora) {
    this.daoExpedBitacora = daoExpedBitacora;
    }
....
```

And in other Manager Implementation classes, I don't see this part. Must be some mis-click. So I delete this part and it's all fine. Hope I can help some other people.

Comment: Hi! HibernateDaoSupport and HibernateTemplate are deprecated in 2011 - you should use `@Transactional` and getCurrentSession http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why (if you are not tied to Spring 2.5 of course)

Comment: Yes I know that, thanks. I have to study that and I will. Now I am following old code of previous colleagues.