# I can't diplay a list with JSF,Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I'm creating a web application with Netbeans using Spring, Hibernate and JSf. when I run my application I have no error and the application is deployed but in my JSF the list is not appeared

[image]

I don't know what I have to do
Please help me and thanks in advance

My listUniv.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:head/>
  <h:body>
    <h1>Liste des universités</h1>
        <h:form id="mainForm">
                    <h:outputText value="#{fn:length(universiteBean.listUniversites)}" />

    <p:dataList id="lista" var="Universite1" value="#{universiteBean.listUniversites}" emptyMessage="aucune universite trouvée!">
        <li><h:outputText value="#{Universite1.libelle}" />  
        </li>
    </p:dataList>

                <p:commandButton value="ajouter" action="#{universiteBean.nouveau()}"/>

        </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>listUniv.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<!--  1ere  -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!--  2 eme -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <!--        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>-->
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>

</context-param>

</web-app>
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">


<!-- BEAN DE LA DATA SOURCE -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/formadb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean> 

<!-- BEAN DE LA FABRIQUE DE SPRING avec definition du mapping-->
<bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="configLocation" >
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

<!-- Ajout d'un bean de gestion des transactions -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <!-- Lui définir le sessionFactory qui devra exploiter -->
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"/>          
</bean>


<!-- BEAN UNIVERSITE -->
<bean id="universiteDao" class="dao.UniversiteDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactoryBean"/>
    </property>        
</bean>
<bean id="universiteMetier" class="metier.UniversiteMetier" init-method="init">
    <property name="universiteDao" ref="universiteDao"/>
</bean>


<!-- BEAN COMPOSANTE-->
<bean id="composanteDao" class="dao.ComposanteDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactoryBean"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="composanteMetier" class="metier.ComposanteMetier">
    <property name="composanteDao" ref="composanteDao"/>
</bean>
```

I Used mapping class in hibernate.cfg.xml

My Dao class:

```
package dao;

import entites.Universite;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class UniversiteDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IUniversiteDao{


@Override
public void addUniversite(Universite universite) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(universite);
}

@Override
public void updateUniversite(Universite univ) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(univ);
}

@Override
public void deleteUniversite(Universite univ) {
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(univ);
}

@Override
public List findListUniversite() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from entites.Universite");
}

@Override
public Universite findUniversite(String libelle) {
    List l= getHibernateTemplate().find("from entites.Universite univ where univ.libelle='"+libelle+"'");
    if (l.size()> 0) {
        return (Universite) l.get(0);
    } else 
        return null;
}

public void init() {
    System.out.println("-------UniversiteDaoImp-----------");
}
}
```

My Class Service

```
package metier;

import dao.IUniversiteDao;
import entites.Universite;
import exceptions.ObjtNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

public class UniversiteMetier implements IUniversiteMetier{

private IUniversiteDao universiteDao;

public void setUniversiteDao(IUniversiteDao universiteDao) {
    this.universiteDao = universiteDao;
}

@Override
public void addUniversite(String libelle, String abreviation, String description) {
    Universite univ= new Universite(libelle, abreviation, description);
    universiteDao.addUniversite(univ);
}

@Override
public void updateUniversite(String libelle, String abreviation, String description) throws ObjtNotFoundException {
    Universite univ= universiteDao.findUniversite(libelle);
    if (univ== null) {
        throw new ObjtNotFoundException();
    }
    univ.setLibelle(libelle);
    universiteDao.updateUniversite(univ);
}

@Override
public List findListUniversite() {
    return universiteDao.findListUniversite();
}

@Override
public Universite findUniversite(String libelle) throws ObjtNotFoundException {
    Universite univ= universiteDao.findUniversite(libelle);
    if (univ== null) {
        System.out.println("universite introuvable!!!");
        throw new ObjtNotFoundException();
    }
    return univ;
}

@Override
public void deleteUniversite(String libelle) throws ObjtNotFoundException {
    Universite univ= universiteDao.findUniversite(libelle);
    if (univ== null) {
        throw new ObjtNotFoundException();
    }
    universiteDao.deleteUniversite(univ);
}

public void init(){
System.out.println("-------UniversiteMetierImp-----------");
}
}
```

and my Bean

```
package web;

import entites.Universite;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import metier.UniversiteMetier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("universiteBean")
//@Scope("session")
@ViewScoped
public class UniversiteBean implements Serializable{

private List<Universite> listUniversites;
@Autowired
private transient UniversiteMetier universiteMetier;

private Universite universite;

public UniversiteBean() {
}

    @PostConstruct
public void init(){
    refresh();
    System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeee"+listUniversites.size());
}

public void refresh(){
    listUniversites= universiteMetier.findListUniversite();
}

public List<Universite> getListUniversites() {
    return listUniversites;
}

public void setListUniversites(List<Universite> listUniversites) {
    this.listUniversites = listUniversites;
}

public UniversiteMetier getUniversiteMetier() {
    return universiteMetier;
}

public void setUniversiteMetier(UniversiteMetier universiteMetier) {
    this.universiteMetier = universiteMetier;
}

public Universite getUniversite() {
    return universite;
}

public void setUniversite(Universite universite) {
    this.universite = universite;
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, narrow the problem to see if its related to JSF, Hibernate or whatever it is. Use an IDE with a debugger. Can you see `listUniversites` properly loaded?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thank you for replying, I used Junit test and listUniversites was loaded correctly, but trying to do the same thing in my JSF it wasn't loaded, i think i mistake in configuration and I can't find what the problem 
(and I'm sorry I don't speak english well )

Comment: @Filip Thanks for the input. And thanks for the link 
I'm a beginner, I will try to fix the problem, if it doesn't work I will try to use the alternative with Repository annotation

Comment: Can you narrow this code down to a Minimal, Verifiable, Example? You should put some System.out.println debug statements in to see if things are working like you think they should? Does the PostConstruct get called? Does it put items in the list? Can you JSF page find your web bean? What if you put hardcoded items in the list, does the primefaces datalist work on that? This is the answer to your question. I don't see anything obviously wrong at first glance.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED: Please narrow this code down to a Minimal, Verifiable, Example. You should put some System.out.println debug statements in to see if things are working like you think they should. See if the `PostConstruct` gets called. Add a debug statment to find out if the `PostConstruct` puts items in the list and update the question. If `PostConstruct` routine is not invoked, the `JSF` page bean is annotated wrong or referenced improperly. Put hardcoded items in the list and determine whether primefaces datalist is setup properly. These are tried and true debug techniques that every programmer needs to understand and master.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that you don't want you bean as a `Component`. That means you are building a unique JSF component. Try `ManagedBean`.

Comment: 5 questions in this and then calling it an answer ;-) (but you are right, these steps should be taken) Please make a comment out of this

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks a lot, you're right, and i'm just a beginner 
at first I tried with #{fn:length(universiteBean.listeUniversites)} to know if the list is loaded and it wasn't 
I used a Junit Test and the list was loaded correctly, i think that the problem is with the PostConstruct which is not called, So I'll work with your advice and try to find out what's wrong, 
if you could please help me 
(excuse me I don't speak English well )

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for comments, I updated the response.

Comment: :-) and you **can** delete this answer then…

Comment: I could, but why would I? The OP has a general question for which my general answers are helpful. OP may follow my advice, find the solution, and give me credit for the answer. Others may do the same. Why else would I be posting on SO?