# Spring-Hibernate 5 Support JAR files

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying to migrate Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.0.11 and I have downloaded and imported the Hibernate 5.0.11 core jar files. But when I try start my apache tomcat server on my IDE, it shows the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
```

This is because I am not able to download the Spring-Hibernate5 jar files.
Can anyone guide me to download and install those jar files.

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to download and manage your dependencies manually, since you can forget a required lib. Just let Maven (or other dependencies management tool) handle it for you:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Other spring libs -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The class is located into spring-orm project, since its version 4.2.

However, it is already known that `HibernateDaoSupport` is not the best solution for your purposes anymore, take a look: [Why is HibernateDaoSupport not recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/why-is-hibernatedaosupport-not-recommended)