# How to insert into HSQL from a thymeleaf form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf, hsqldb

Controller

```
    package com.hellokoding.hello.web;
    import com.hellokoding.hello.pojo.*;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import com.hellokoding.hello.dao.*;

    @Controller
    public class HelloController {

        @Autowired 
        StudentDAO studentDao;


        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "input";
        }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
                Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            return "hello";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/studentRegister", params = {"save"})
        public String saveSeedstarter(final Student student, final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model) {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return "input";
            }
            model.addAttribute("student", student);
            studentDao.saveStudent(student);
            return "result";
        }

        @ModelAttribute("student")
        public Student getStudent(){
            return new Student();
        }


        /*
         * @RequestMapping(value = "/studentRegister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
         * public String index(@RequestParam(value="save") Student student, Model
         * model) { model.addAttribute("student", student); return "hello"; }
         */
    }
```

Hsql db in

[image: eclipse]

The url is jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb

[image: properties]

I dunno where the db files will be??. If i open in database manager then i cannot see the student database. Help me to fix this

[image: Cannot see the table here]

I have the form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>        
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">        
    <head>
    <title>Spring Thyme Seed Starter Manager</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>        
    <body>
        <h2>Add new student</h2>        
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/studentRegister}"
            th:object="${student}" method="post">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
            </form>        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Hello Spring MVC</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

appconfig-root.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <import resource="appconfig-mvc.xml"/>

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Component classes to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hellokoding.hello.*"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

</beans>
```

appconfig-mvc.xml

```
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />


    </bean>
        <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>WEB-INF/configuration.properties</value>
                </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${jdbc.driver.className}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hellokoding.hello.pojo" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I need to submit the form i have added the it to student model attribute in controller. I need to insert this data into student db of HSQL.  How to proceed with modifications in spring xml.

I have included a persistence.xml under resources/META-INF

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
      <persistence-unit name="manager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.hellokoding.hello</class>
      <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

configuration.properties

```
     jdbc.driver.className=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
     jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb
     jdbc.username=sa
     jdbc.password=
     jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

DAO interface

```
    package com.hellokoding.hello.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.hellokoding.hello.pojo.Student;

    public interface StudentDAO {
        public void saveStudent(Student student);
        public List<Student> getAllStudents(Student student);
        public Student getStudentById(String studentId);
        public void deleteStudent(Student student);
    }
```

DAO implementation

```
    package com.hellokoding.hello.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.hellokoding.hello.pojo.Student;

    //This will make easier to autowired
    @Repository("StudentDAO")
    @Transactional
    public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {
        private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

        @Autowired
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        }

        @Transactional(readOnly = false)
        public void saveStudent(Student student) {
            System.out.println("Inside");
            hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(student);

        }

        @Transactional(readOnly = false)
        public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
            hibernateTemplate.delete(student);

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Student> getAllStudents(Student student) {
            return (List<Student>) hibernateTemplate.find("from " + Student.class.getName());
        }

        public Student getStudentById(String studentId) {
            return hibernateTemplate.get(Student.class, studentId);
        }
    }
```

I have tried with hibernate and i was trying to insert into the db.

Student Bean

```
    package com.hellokoding.hello.pojo;    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    //import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student_table")
    public class Student implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static long getSerialversionuid() {
            return serialVersionUID;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
        private String firstName;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }


        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
        private String lastName;

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public Student(){

        }

        public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;       
        }

    }
```

The id is also not generating and its not inserting the HSQL db table called student_table

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hellokoding</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Hello Spring MVC</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- embedded Jetty server, for testing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `HibernateTemplate` is considered deprecated -
 don't bother using it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/why-is-hibernatedaosupport-not-recommended

Comment: Ok thank you so much...