# Bean property 'sessionFactoy' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

Working on spring+hibernate+maven code.

here's my StockDaoImpl class..

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import com.mkyong.stock.dao.StockDao;
import com.mkyong.stock.model.Stock;

public class StockDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements StockDao{

    public void save(Stock stock){
        getHibernateTemplate().save(stock);
    }
```

...

My sessionfactory defined in an xml..

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">


        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>    
        </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibenate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/Hibernate/Stock.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

I get the following error in console..Bean property 'sessionFactoy' is not writable or has an invalid setter method...

I tried writing a setter function for sessionfactory in StockDaoImpl...But I get an error saying 'setSessionFactory() in HibernateDaoSupport cannot be overridden'.

Can anyone pls tell me how to resolve the issue..

Comment: suppose you have to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of what you have used. please see this [post](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/) it may be helpful.

Comment: This looks like you mis-spelt `sessionFactory` as `sessionFactoy` in the section of your XML that consumes the sessionFactory.

Comment: I recommend you to read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/why-is-hibernatedaosupport-not-recommended). So don't use HibernateDaoSupport. As already sad, you can't mix the versions.

Comment: Thank you!It's working now.!!